# How to compare an id to a value in Iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Please see the code below,

```
-(void) dataFromURL:(NSString *)url withRef:(id)ref
{

if(ref==@"Category")
     Printf("category");       //I need control here but control doesn't come here.<br>  
else
     printf("Subcategory");

}
```

How i will compare id datatype(ref) to a value like-Category? when I print ref through `NSLog(@"ID %@",ref);` It returns as *Category:0xd28f50* in angular brackets.

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple.....i got it
[ref isKindOfClass:[Category class]].

:)